# How to correctly use x265 lossless parameter with avconv

Tags: video-conversion, video-encoding, libav, lossless

`x265` has a lossless mode which is used for ultra-high bitrates with zero loss of quality. I tried using this mode with `avconv` as follows:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless -c:a copy output.mp4
```

However, using this mode has an opposite effect : video came out to be of extremely low quality. It was totally lossy!!

Am I using the parameter incorrectly? Or am I somehow misunderstanding the definition of the word "lossless"?

#### Important Links:

- Lossless mode of x265: http://x265.readthedocs.org/en/default/lossless.html
- How to use x265 parameters in `avconv`: https://wiki.libav.org/Encoding/hevc

Comment: Should it not be --lossless ?

Comment: @Linef4ult : No. That doesn't work. `--lossless` is used when using the `x265` binary directly. However, when using `avconv`, parameters are passed differently. For example, CRF value is passed as `--crf 28` when using `x265` directly, however it is passed as `-x265-params crf=28` when using `avconv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg/Libav require a "key=value" format so it requires a "=1". So for your example:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

To confirm if it works (via command line) you should see the following log:

```
x265 [info]: Rate Control                        : Lossless
```

Refs:

- http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/372625-ffmpeg-does-not-apply-parameters-with-libx265?s=7964e1f31383b6144370dabc6e04706f&p=2397346&viewfull=1#post2397346

Comment: This does work!! Thanks @TheBiggerGuy. I tried converting a x264 file to x265 losslessly, and it worked. The file size of x265 came out to be larger, which was kind of a bummer, though not unexpected. I will accept your answer soon after a bit of further testing.